# Routing Not Working in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to AngularJS, and I'm attempting to set up routing on my basic app.

My app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("StarWarsApp", ['ngRoute', 'ne.swapi']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
   $routeProvider 
    .when('/', { 
      controller: 'HomeController', 
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html' 
    }) 
     .otherwise({ 
  redirectTo: '/' 
}); 
});
```

My index.html:

```
    <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="StarWarsApp" \>
     <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<!-- Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/charactersList.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/ne-swapi/dist/ne-swapi.min.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

When I load home.html directly, I see the contents of it properly, but it won't appear in my ng-view and I can't figure out why. I'm sure I missed something very basic, but I've no idea. Any ideas?

Comment: if you are new to angularJS why do you use such an outdated angularjs Version?

Answer (score 0):

What you posted works correctly without your controller, service, and ne.swapi, so the error is likely there. However the code for your controller & service was not posted here.

One idea I have from referencing the ne.swapi documentation-check that you are loading 'swapi' after $scope in the controller if you are using ne.swapi. Again, since your controller was not posted I am not sure if this is causing the issue.

```
app.controller("Test", function($scope, swapi){
    $scope.test = "Hey";
});
```

I have a working plunker here, I hope referencing it will help you find the error. https://plnkr.co/edit/9hD490m7nZxSTQPDTN0J?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Issues Found:

1. There is an unexpected character in the body tag. Remove that first.
2. Also, you have added the 'ne.swapi' dependency in app.js. So, its script should be added before inserting app.js.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script`>

`<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script`>

`<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/ne-swapi/dist/ne-swapi.min.js"></script`>

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script`>

3. Also, it would be good to add scripts in the bottom of the body tag. Otherwise. it might affect the page rendering speed. This is a suggestion. This won't cause the issue you have now.